# Restrict upload to file extensions in jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to perform validation with the jQuery Validation plugin for `input` `type="file"`.  I want to restrict file formats to `doc,pdf,rtf, and docx`.

Here is my code:

```
  $("#contact-form").validate({ 
          onfocusout: function(e) {
              this.element(e);
            },
        rules:{

            resume:{
                required:true,
                extension: "docx|rtf|doc|pdf"
            }

        },
    resume:{
                required:"input type is required",                  
                extension:"select valied input file format"
            }


    });
```

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Jq93a/1/

Comment: thanks arun i changed my question

Comment: Your code is working, so what exactly is the problem?    Did you remember to include the `additional-methods.js` file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You never explained the problem you're having with your code:

```
$("#contact-form").validate({ 
    onfocusout: function(e) {
        this.element(e);
    },
    rules:{
        resume:{
            required:true,
            extension: "docx|rtf|doc|pdf"
        }
    },
    resume:{
        required:"input type is required",                  
        extension:"select valied input file format"
    }
});
```

However, you're declaring messages without using the `messages` option.  This is an error that would likely break the plugin, or at the least, your custom error messages would be ignored.

Your code should look like this...

```
$("#contact-form").validate({ 
    onfocusout: function(e) {  // this option is not needed
        this.element(e);       // this is the default behavior
    },
    rules:{
        resume:{
            required:true,
            extension: "docx|rtf|doc|pdf"
        }
    },
    messages: {  // <-- you must declare messages inside of "messages" option
        resume:{
            required:"input type is required",                  
            extension:"select valid input file format"
        }
    }
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZqxR2/**

Comment: thanks sparkly same code i am wriiten in my application it is only accepting pdf file if we include doc file it is showing error

Comment: @sarath, My demo is working perfectly so the problem has nothing to do with any code you've shown us.

Comment: I have tried to implement this demo but its not working.As like here i have implemented jquery.min,jquery.validate and additional-extension.js but still its not working.whether i have to add any thing elser?

Comment: @user2089987, What exactly does "not working" mean?  Have you looked at your error console?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to create rule

just use accept attribute in input like below

`<input type="file" accept="doc,pdf,rtf,docx"/>`

Comment: The user could just change the filetype in the dialog so better to have additional validation.

Answer (score 0):

Today I needed that script and I could not find.. I made own script (works almost for all browser, even IE). I would like notice I am beginner with jQuery, but I am trying to do something new:

[Open JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0z4rg7kL/)

Here example:

```js
$('#file').on('change', function() {
 var numb = $(this)[0].files[0].size/1024/1024; //count file size
var resultid = $(this).val().split(".");
var gettypeup  = resultid [resultid.length-1]; // take file type uploaded file
var filetype = $(this).attr('data-file_types'); // take allowed files from input
var allowedfiles = filetype.replace(/\|/g,', '); // string allowed file
var tolovercase = gettypeup.toLowerCase();
var filesize = 2; //2MB
var onlist = $(this).attr('data-file_types').indexOf(tolovercase) > -1;
var checkinputfile = $(this).attr('type');
numb = numb.toFixed(2);

if (onlist && numb <= filesize) {
   $('#alert').html('The file is ready to upload').removeAttr('class').addClass('xd2'); //file OK
   } else {
   if(numb >= filesize && onlist){
  $(this).val(''); //remove uploaded file
      $('#alert').html('Added file is too big \(' + numb + ' MB\) - max file size '+ filesize +' MB').removeAttr('class').addClass('xd'); //alert that file is too big, but type file is ok
      } else if(numb < filesize && !onlist) {
     $(this).val(''); //remove uploaded file
      $('#alert').html('An not allowed file format has been added \('+ gettypeup +') - allowed formats: ' + allowedfiles).removeAttr('class').addClass('xd'); //wrong type file
      } else if(!onlist) {
    $(this).val(''); //remove uploaded file
      $('#alert').html('An not allowed file format has been added \('+ gettypeup +') - allowed formats: ' + allowedfiles).removeAttr('class').addClass('xd'); //wrong type file
      }
   }
})
```

```css
body{background:#fff}

#alert.xd{background:#ff9e9e; border:1px solid #ff0000;
color: #000;
padding:5px;
border-radius:10px}

#alert.xd2{background:#9effb3; border:1px solid #00de26;
color: #000;
padding:5px;
border-radius:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<input type="file" id="file" data-file_types="pdf|doc|docx|rtf|odt|jpg|jpeg">
<br><br>
Allowed files:<br><br>
<div id="allowed-files"></div>
<br><br>
<div id="allowed-size"></div>

<div id="alert"></div>
<script>
var title = $( "#file" ).attr( "data-file_types" ).replace(/\|/g,', ');
$( "#allowed-files" ).text( title );
</script>
```

If there is some faults in my code, please let me know :) Thank you.

Also I can answer for questions in the comments.